# Django: Time to match time on server

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-settings

When I submit a form I capture the date and time by setting `default=timezone.now` in my model. The captured time is 4 hours ahead of the server time. I've read through the documentation and have played around with these guys below, but still can't get them to match. How can I get django to use my server time?

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the Option `USE_TZ` is enabled, you realy need to set what is your Time Zone in the `TIME_ZONE` Option.
Here a link with all Options Available: [Time Zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Django Framework provide a WebView in order to help you to choose what is your Time Zone. You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone)

Hope It Helps you.

Comment: Thanks. So tried setting `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'`, but still no dice. Any other suggestions. I also restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

The timezone on your settings.py should match the timezone on your operating system. If you're using Debian/Ubuntu, run:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

to configure and see your current time zone.